# X compact iff any collection of closed set closed by finite intersection have a nonempty intersection

Tags: general-topology, analysis, compactness

I've got a problem to show something. Actually, we consider $X$ a topological space , and we want to show :

$X$ compact $\iff \forall (F_i)_{i \in I} $ collection of closed set which is closed by finite intersection : $\bigcap_{i \in I} F_i \neq \emptyset$

It's okay for the direction $\implies$. But for the other direction, I'm stuck. Actually, this is what I did :

Let $(O_i)_{i \in I} \in (\mathcal{O}_X)^I$ such that : $X = \bigcup_{i \in I} O_i$. If there is $i_0 \in I$ such that $U_{i_0} = X$, then $X = U_{i_0}$ and it's okay. Otherwise, we have :

$X = (\bigcap_{i \in I} U_i{}^c)^c$, and we consider the collection : $(U_i^{c})_{i \in I}$ which is a collection of closed subset. Then, I tried different things, I mainly try to introduce a set as : $\mathcal{A} = \{ J \subset I \; | \; J$ finite and $ (U_j^{c})_{j \in J}$ closed by finite intersection $\}$ or other set like this in order to find a $J \subset I$, $J$ a finite set, which verify : $\bigcup_{j \in J} U_j = X$. But I didn't find.

If someone could help me, it will be very appreciated !

Thank you !

Comment: You have to mention that your closed sets are non-empty. Otherwise the statement is obviously false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the reverse direction I would recommend arguing by contrapositive.

**Claim:** If $X$ is not compact, then there exists a family of closed sets $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ that is closed under finite intersections, such that $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in I} U_{\alpha} = \varnothing.$

**Proof:** Suppose $X$ is not compact. Then, there exists an open cover $\{V_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ for $X$ which does not admit a finite subcover. We will assume without loss of generality that for all $\alpha \in I$, $V_{\alpha} \neq \varnothing$. As such, we may for all $\alpha \in I$ define $V_{\alpha} = U_{\alpha}^{C}$ so that $\mathscr{G}=\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I} \subseteq \mathscr{P}(X)$ is a family of nonempty, closed sets. Fix a finite subset $J \subset I$. Since $\{V_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ does not admit a finite subcover, 
$$\varnothing \neq \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in J} V_{\alpha} \subset X \implies \varnothing \neq \bigg(\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in J} V_{\alpha}\bigg)^{C} \subset X. $$ 
But from our definition of $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ and de Morgan's Law, it follows that
$$\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in J}U_{\alpha}=\bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in J}V_{\alpha}^{C}=\bigg(\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in J} V_{\alpha}\bigg)^{C} \neq \varnothing.$$
Since $J \subset I$ was an arbitrary finite set, we conclude that $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ has the finite intersection property. Now constructing the set 
$$\mathscr{A}:=\{J \in \mathscr{P}(I):\textrm{J finite}\}$$ and letting $I'$ be an indexing set for $\mathscr{A}$ so that $\mathscr{A}=\{J_{\beta}\}_{\beta \in I'}$, we in turn construct the family of sets $\mathscr{H}=\{W_{\beta}\}_{\beta \in I'}$ such that for each $\beta \in I'$, $W_{\beta}=\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in J_{\beta}}U_{\alpha}$. Further defining $\mathscr{I}=I \cup I'$, and $\mathscr{F}=\mathscr{G} \cup \mathscr{H}$, we see that $\mathscr{F} =\{K_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in \mathscr{I}}\subseteq \mathscr{P}(X)$ is a family of closed sets which is closed under finite intersections, with $$\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \mathscr{I}}K_{\alpha}=\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in I}U_{\alpha}.$$
However, since the $\{V_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ are an open cover for $X$ by assumption, we may again invoke the definition of $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ to show that
$$\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \mathscr{I}}K_{\alpha}=\bigcap_{\alpha \in I}U_{\alpha}=\bigcap_{\alpha \in I}V_{\alpha}^{C}=\bigg(\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in I} V_{\alpha}\bigg)^{C} =X^{C}=\varnothing,$$
which is what we promised to show.

Regards!
-Dan

Comment: Okay, thank you. The only problem I have with your proof, is that the contrapositive is : $X$ not compact $\implies \exists (U_{i})_{i \in I}$ of closed subspace, which is closed by finite intersection, which verify : $\bigcap U_{i} = \emptyset$. And here, how do we know that the $(U_{\alpha})$ you found is closed by finite intersection ? Maybe, $V_1^{c} \cap  V_2^{c} \notin (V_{\alpha}^{c})_{\alpha}$, no ?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I have the impression that I'm missing something... Why the $(U_{i})$ would be closed under finite intersection ? It means that if I takes $i, j$, then : $U_i \cap U_j = (V_i \cup V_j)^{c} \in (U_i)_{i}$, so $V_{i} \cup V_{j} = V_{k}, k \in I$. But why it could be the case ?

Comment: But why ? Really, I don't see why... Let's take $|J| = 2$, and as I explained in my comment just below yours, why $U_i \cap U_j = (V_i \cup V_j)^{c}$ would be on $((V_k)^{c})_{k \in I}$. Actually, if $U_i \cap U_j \neq \emptyset$, then $\forall x \in U_i \cap U_j \; \exists k_x \in I  \backslash \{i,j\} \;  x \in V_{k_x}$. But $k_x$ is depending of $x$, and then maybe we have not the same $k$ for all the $x$, for example we could have : $U_i \cap U_j = V_{k_1} \cup V_{k_2}$, with $k_1 \neq k_2$ and $V_{k_1} \cup V_{k_2} \notin (V_k)_{k \in I}$, and then $U_i \cap U_j \notin (U_k)_{k \in I}$.

Comment: If we take $|J|=2$, since $V_{i}, V_{j}$ are nonempty it is clear that $\varnothing \neq V_{i} \cup V_{j} \subset X$ Then since $U_{i}=V_{i}^{C}$, same for $U_{j}$, we see that $$U_{i} \cap U_{j}=V_{i}^{C} \cap V_{j}^{C} =(V_{i} \cup V_{j})^{C},$$ which is nonempty.

Comment: We are okay on the fact that $(V_k)_{k \in I} = \{V_k | k \in I\}$, and then $U_i \cap U_j \in (V_k)_{k \in I} \iff U_i \cap U_j = V_l$ for $l \in I$ ? Then, $U_i = V_i^{c}$ and $U_j \in V_j^{c}$, so $U_i \cap U_j = V_i^{c} \cap V_j^{c} = (V_i \cup V_j)^{c}$, but it doesn't mean that $V_i \cup V_j \in (V_k)_{k \in I}$ cause maybe this last collection is not even closed under finite union. Cause in fact, we have to show that $(U_i)_i$ is closed under finite intersection, and we didn't...

Comment: I have the impression that all we've proven is that $(U_i)_i$  has the finite intersection property, which not implies that $(U_i)_i$ is closed under finite intersection.

Comment: I have used "finite intersection property" in the proof to indicate this. It was my impression that this is what you meant, as the standard topological result involves families of sets with the finite intersection property. If you really want the family of sets to be closed under finite intersection in the sense that any finite intersection of these sets also belongs to the family, then append all finite intersections to the family. This should not affect the result of the proof otherwise.

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you very much, now it's clear ! So, when we say "closed under finite intersection", when we talk about topological spaces, it's not in the sense that any finite intersection of these sets also belongs to the family but in the sense of $\bigcap_{j \in J} U_j \neq \emptyset$ for $J \subset I$, $J$ a finite set, right ?

Comment: Okay, thank you !

Comment: In most contexts, "finite intersection property" means that finite intersections of sets in a family have non-empty intersection, while "closed under finite intersection" means that finite intersections of members of the family are also members of the family. In this setting I have only ever seen people refer to the FIP but in any case I have updated the proof to reflect what you were asking for, now that I understand

Comment: Okay, thank you very much ! It's perfect ! :)